# validate column of polymorphic table

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `flask-sqlalchemy` polymorphic table structure like so

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    polytype = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)

    value = db.Column(db.String(32))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'parent',
                       'polymorphic_on': polytype}


class Child(Parent):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('parent.id'),
                   primary_key=True)

    @validates('value')
    def validate_value(self, key, val):
        # [validation code]
        return value

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}
```

and I want to validate the value field. However, the validator for `Child.value`, the column inherited from `Parent`, never runs.

What is the correct way to validate an inherited column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an old [open issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/2943) about it.

In that issue, it is suggested that using an event listener can work, for example:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    polytype = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)

    value = db.Column(db.String(32))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'parent',
                       'polymorphic_on': polytype}


class Child(Parent):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('parent.id'),
                   primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}


@event.listens_for(Parent.value, "set", propagate=True)
def validate_value(inst, val, *args):
    print(f"checking value for {inst}")
    assert val == "spam"


Parent(value="spam")
Child(value="spam")
```

If you don't want the listener to fire on `Parent` instances, decorate your listener func with `event.listens_for(Child.value, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this known open issue is creating an instance method to be called inside the @validate method, for example:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
from sqlalchemy import event

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    polytype = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String(32))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'parent',
                       'polymorphic_on': polytype}


    @validates('value')
    def validate_value(self, key, new_value):
        self._validate_value(new_value)

    

    def _validate_value(self, new_value):
        print(f"checking value for {self}")
        assert new_value == "spam"

class Child(Parent):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('parent.id'),
                   primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}


    def _validate_value(self, new_value):
        print(f"checking value for {self}")
        assert new_value == "child"



Parent(value="spam")
Child(value="child")
```

In this case, you are able to validate the value having different behaviors on the Childs overwriting the private method **_validate_value**